# Unable to kill excel processes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, process

I am using the followiwing code to do some copying and pasting with excel files:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Private Sub btnCombine_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCombine.Click

    Dim xlAppSource As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlAppTarget As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWbSource As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWbTarget As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlsheetSource As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlsheetTarget As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlRangeSource As Excel.Range
    Dim xlRangeTarget As Excel.Range

    Dim Progress As Integer = 0
    pbrProgress.Minimum = 0
    pbrProgress.Maximum = amountOfFiles

    btnCombine.Enabled = False
    btnSelect.Enabled = False
    pbrProgress.Visible = True

    getSaveLocation()
    MakeExcelFile()

    'loop through all excel files to get the required data
    For i = 0 To amountOfFiles - 1


        Dim CurrentFile As String = strFileNames(i)
        Dim IntAmountOfRows As Integer = amountOfRows(CurrentFile)
        Dim intStartOfEmptyRow As Integer = amountOfRows(SummaryLocation)

        xlAppSource.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlAppTarget.DisplayAlerts = False

        'Set current workbook
        xlWbSource = xlAppSource.Workbooks.Open(CurrentFile)
        xlWbTarget = xlAppTarget.Workbooks.Open(SummaryLocation)

        'set current worksheet
        xlsheetSource = xlWbSource.ActiveSheet
        xlsheetTarget = xlWbTarget.ActiveSheet

        'copy range of data from source to target file
        xlRangeSource = xlsheetSource.Range("A2:k" & IntAmountOfRows)
        xlRangeSource.Copy()

        xlRangeTarget = xlsheetTarget.Range("A" & intStartOfEmptyRow)
        xlRangeTarget.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues)

        'save summary file before closing
        xlsheetTarget.SaveAs(SummaryLocation)

        'updating progress bar
        Progress = Progress + 1
        pbrProgress.Value = Progress

    Next

    'close excel
    xlWbSource.Close(True)
    xlWbTarget.Close(True)
    xlAppSource.Quit()
    xlAppTarget.Quit()

    xlAppSource.DisplayAlerts = True
    xlAppTarget.DisplayAlerts = True


    'Cleanup
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlAppSource)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlAppTarget)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWbSource)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWbTarget)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlsheetSource)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlsheettarget)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRangeSource)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRangeTarget)

    xlAppSource = Nothing
    xlAppTarget = Nothing
    xlWbSource = Nothing
    xlWbTarget = Nothing
    xlsheetSource = Nothing
    xlsheetTarget = Nothing
    xlRangeSource = Nothing
    xlRangeTarget = Nothing

    MsgBox("Samenvoegen compleet")

    init()

End Sub
```

I have tried every solution given on SO:

- Never use 2 points on a line
- I have tried using marshall.ReleaseComObject
- I have tried setting the objects to "Nothing"

However, everytime I run the application, there will be 10-20 excel processes still running.

Comment: You forgot tmpSource and tmpTarget. Actually, you don't need them, can replace xlWbTarget = tmpTarget.Open(SummaryLocation) with xlWbTarget = xlAppTarget.Workbooks.Open(SummaryLocation). Not sure about the exact point of DisplayAlerts after the objects have been quitted. Also you might uncomment the last bunch of Nothing (at least the App object ones). If you do all that, when you close your application, there would not be any running Excel process.

Comment: PS: I realised now (after reading your comment below) that you are creating/disposing Excel objects inside a loop. You don't need to do that (actually is HIGHLY UNRECOMMENDABLE, precisely because of the problems associated with releasing Excel objects); you can use the same objects over and over and only releasing them before closing the application. If you need to open different Excel Windows, create as many objects as windows you need.

Comment: The reason I made the tmpTarget is because on a different question, people were told never to use more than 1 dot (.) with interop

Comment: I don't understand the last reasoning but you are free to use tmpTarget if you wish; although you have to release it too. In any case, as said in my previous PS, you should change your code: the Excel Object releasing process should be done once, at the end, when you don't need the objects anymore. Inside the loop, you should either keep the same objects or create as many different objects as different Excel windows you want (all these should be released when you are done with them).

Comment: @varocarbas I have changed my code with your suggestions in mind. Yet the processes keep existing. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I am closing the workbooks, quitting the applications, releasing the objects and then setting them to nothing.

Comment: If, after completing the loop (and all the actions with the objects), you write your object-releasing code (by accounting for all the objects + the final Nothings). When you close the application, there will not be any running Excel instance. To do the test, make sure that there are not Excel objects from previous executions (no running Excel process when starting).

Comment: @varocarbas Oh yes! you are right. I never closed my Form before checking the processes!

Comment: Closing the app is the safest way; and if you don't mind this small bit (having running Excel instances while the program is running), why complicating things more?

Comment: @varocarbas You are right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

    xlApp.Visible = False
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim xlWb As Workbook
    Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\...\path")

    Dim xlSht As Worksheet
    Set xlSht = xlWb.Sheets(1)

    xlSht.Range("A1") = "message from " & ThisWorkbook.FullName

    xlWb.Saved = True
    xlWb.Save
    xlWb.Close

    xlApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Works for me every single time and does not leave any Excel processes hanging in the task manager.

**Note:** if your code breaks at some point and you do not handle the already opened objects properly then they will just hang in the processes tab in the Task Manager. If you haven't implemented error handling in your code then start [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm).

just consider this as alternative

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

    xlApp.Visible = False
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim xlWb As Workbook
    Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\...\path")

    Dim xlSht As Worksheet
    Set xlSht = xlWb.Sheets(1)

    xlSht.Range("A1") = "message from " & ThisWorkbook.FullName

    xlWb.Saved = True
    xlWb.Save
    xlWb.Close

    xlApp.Quit
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    xlWb.Saved = True
    xlWb.Save
    xlWb.Close

    xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry to say but this is not how things work with Interop Excel. The Excel processes do remain and you have to do quite a lot to remove them (on the lines of what the OP did). Not sure why you don't see it with your code, perhaps because of .Visible = False or just using one Excel object, but this is certainly a problematic issue.

Comment: As you can see in my code, I am already using the .save, .close and .quit in my application. However, it keeps on piling the excel processes up untill the point that my application crashes because it thinks someone still has an excel file open that I am trying to use. `Note: Before I run the app, I make sure that all excel processes are terminated, so It cant be old instances

Comment: @Gutanoth did you read the part about error handling? you NEED that in your code in order to control what is going on. Add a debug.print line in the ErrHandler to see if there are errors while processing the files. `Kill`ing Excel processes is not considered error handling but a way of escaping the trouble. If you had a proper error handling coded within your macro then you shouldn't have left any unwanted processes.

Comment: @mehow Yes sorry, I have added that to my application after I posted the updated Question.

Comment: Ah! I see what is the problem here. The OP is not asking for a VBA/Macro solution, but for a VB.NET (coupled via Interop with Excel). Your answer and what you propose works in VBA but not exactly in VB.NET (mainly the running Excel instances bit).

Comment: @varocarbas yeah i see that now. Still a try-catch-finally equivalent in VB.net should handle that. It's all about proper error handling, aint it?

Comment: Sure. When dealing with files it is always recommendable to set try...catch statements just in case. And when dealing with Excel with all these running instances problems, much more important.

Answer (score 0):

***`The Interop Marshal release doesn't always work because Excel XP and lower suck at releasing.  I had to use your loop, but replace the Process.Close() and Process.Quit()  with Process.Kill().  Works like a charm.  Just be careful that you want ALL versions of excel.exe to be killed, because they will.`***

I use this:

```
Workbook.Save()
Workbook.Close()
Application.Quit()

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Application)

Worksheet = Nothing
Workbook = Nothing
Application = Nothing

Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process

For Each proc In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
proc.Kill()
Next
```

Comment: No doubt that your code works. And I would lie if I would say that I haven't ever used it; but this kind of approaches should only be recommended in case of not having any other option. And here there are other options.

Comment: I am making this for other engineers to use. I am affraid that when they are also using Excel for something else while using my application, they will lose work

Answer (score 0):

When you do anything with the Excel Interop, it creates a new process.

The problem with killing all Excel processes is that you may kill a process that you are working with. You can kill all processes which have been running for a certain length of time (i.e. from a certain timestamp) with:

```
Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process
Dim info As ManagementObject
Dim search As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT ProcessId FROM Win32_process WHERE caption = 'Excel'")
For Each info In search.Get()

    'The string will give you the time that the process started
    'You can then subtract that from the current time to see if you want to kill the process
    Dim TheString As String = info.GetText(TextFormat.Mof).ToString

    'Kill the process according to its ID
    proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(Mid$(TheString, _
                                                    (Len(TheString) - 8), 4))
    proc.CloseMainWindow()
    proc.Refresh()
    If proc.HasExited Then GoTo NoKill
    proc.Kill()
NoKill:
Next
```

You'll need to add:

```
Imports System.Management
```

and add the reference for the 'System.Management' to your project.

Comment: Your code looks alot like the one that Coder suggested. But I don't want to "Accidentally" kill excel processes that another user is working with at the time they use my app

Comment: So then you could only kill the process if it's been open for over X amount of minutes. I'm copying from some code I have here but I think we used Val(Mid$(TheString, 57, 2)) to get the minute that the Excel process started. If you debug TheString, you'll see that it contains the create date / time of the process. BTW, the process name is EXCEL.exe not just EXCEL.

Comment: You could also use "SELECT * FROM Win32_process WHERE caption = 'EXCEL.exe'" That will give you a lot more information about the process. There should be something in there that will let you see which processes you started - and then kill the process based on that data.

Comment: Also, the "SELECT * FROM Win32_process" query only shows processes for the current user. That might help you in determining which processes you created.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but using SQL seems like a very complicated thing to do for this problem to me

Comment: I'm not sure that there is any other way to get the data you need about the running processes - and as far as I found (this was about a year ago) there was no simple way to get the Interop to close the process (or to even not open a new one.) If you do find a better way of doing this I would love to know as this bothered me for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the process ID from the Excel.Application hwnd and use that to kill the process safely.